# XML regular expressions flavor to Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, xml, xsd

Is there a tool or library that translates from the regular expression flavor used in XSD (e.g. as described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html)) to the flavor used by Java's [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class? Or, failing that, a Java regular expression library that can directly handle the XML regular expressions flavor? Or failing that, what is the equivalent Java regular expression for the following XML regular expression?

```
<xs:pattern value="[\w\d][\w\d\-_\.!~\*'\(\)\+=]{2,}"/>
```

Comment: Simply double-escape the back slashes \\

Comment: It should be noted that this regular expression contains a lot of unnecessary escapes. Within `[` and  `]`, many "magic" characters lose their magic. -

Comment: I find it completely outrageous that someone who asks for help writing code has the question accepted, whereas someone who asks if the code already exists should have the question rejected. We should be encouraging and rewarding reuse, not downvoting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, see

http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema#xsdregex

Note however that it targets JDK 1.4 regular expressions, not JDK 1.5. A great deal of its work is concerned with the fact that JDK 1.4 does not properly handle non-BMP characters, a problem which goes away in JDK 1.5. If you find an appropriate version of Saxon, (try 9.1), you will find a version of this code adapted to target JDK 1.5. (More recent versions of Saxon implement the XSD/XPath regex dialect natively.)